# Uneven vertical dashed borders when applying to TD

Tags: html, css, border, css-tables

Is there a way to apply vertical dashed borders to `<td>`'s without them (the borders) merging? I am talking about something like on the attached image - there are 3 `<tr>`'s elements here, each of them containing 2 `<td>`'s. If I apply a `border-right: 1px dashed black` to the `<td>`, this is what a get. There is obviously a longer line between the `<tr>`'s:

[image: dashed border in table]

This is, of course, logical as the border is applied to the `<td>`:

```
.standard_table td {
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    border-right: 1px dashed #1d1d1d;
}
.standard_table td:last-child {
    text-align: justify;
    border-right: none;
}
```

Anybody has some idea how to eliminate the longer line and keep the dashed line uniform without extra markup? I doubt it is possible but there sure are more skilled people out there than me so worth a try asking.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the `col` element:

```css
td {
  padding:1em;
  width:100px;
  }
tr {
  border-bottom:1px solid lightgray
}
col {
  background:linear-gradient(
    to top, 
    black 60%, 
    transparent 60%, 
    transparent ) repeat-y;
  background-size:2px 12px;
}
table {
  margin:auto;
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border:dashed 2px;
  border-left:none;
}
col:nth-child(odd), tr:nth-child(odd) {/*  demo purpose for <col> use */
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  }
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col/>
    <col/>
    <col/>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td<br/>line 2</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
    <td>td</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

drawn from `linear-gradient` + `background-size` and `repeat-y`/`x`

else, border on col , that obviously worked only with Firefox

http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/xbjwLE

Comment: Hm, to be honest I don't see any difference by using the col element, the borders still merge between the rows. How exactly did you mean linear-gradient + background size?

Comment: Correction: this actually works in FF but doesn't work in any webkit browser. (cannot test IE right now)... :-/

Comment: @Fygo, right, so background seems to be like the option left, i'll update the code snippet